# How to get TextView from ListView item?

Tags: java, android

I have following code for making ListView:

```
    SimpleAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(this, DictionaryDbWrapper.getInstance().getAllWords(), 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[]{DictionaryDbHelper.WORD, DictionaryDbHelper.CATEGORY},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
    mList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

It works and show me elements, all correct. Also I have OnItemClickListener with following code for clicking by items:

```
        View view=mList.getSelectedView();

        if (view==null) {
            Toast.makeText(UpdatingWordActivity.this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

But mList.getSelectedView() returns me null also. Why?

UPDATE: why does this cast throw exception:

```
View v=(View)mList.getItemAtPosition(0);
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the string of the text view So that you can use it. OR what kind of functionality please explain more.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `getSelectedView()` is for when you use radio buttons with the listview. See [CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE).  `getItemAtPosition()` just calls `getItem(position)` on the underlying adapter; in your case it's a SimpleAdapter. That casting throws an exception because `SimpleAdapter.getItem()` isn't returning a view, it's returning (I believe) the Map of data that is at the given position in the adapter. Other adapters return other things for the `getItem()` method. For instance, the **CursorAdapter** returns a cursor.

See the answer above for the answer to the first question

Answer (score -1):

Listview `OnItemClickListener` has `View v` as parameter, you need to use this parameter to get text.

Here is Android tutorial on this [topic](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) .

Comment: try this, TextView v=(TextView )mList.getItemAtPosition(0);